Beforeunload unexpected behavior in LWC
Im trying to publish a platform event from a LWC if the browser tab gets closed or the browser itself gets closed. It works fine for both of the cases, however if I repeteadly click on the refresh browser button.
Sometimes the beforeunload related function does not get called. And I need the component to send a notification of disconnection through the apex code that publishes the event.
Is there any workaround that never fails for this, that always when I refresh the page no matter how many clicks I do, or how often I press f5. My platform event gets published through the beforeunload callback.
If there is no any way.
Is there maybe anyway to detect a page status from which the beforeunload event is 100% always going to be called, under normal circumstances (of course not including things like  session ended, or power outage, or things like that, I dont want to get so far anyways).
Im struggling with these (more than 50 hours so far this point) But my component works like this:
It waits untill the readyState == 'complete' then it subscribe to the platform events channel and right after that, it sends a notification to all the subscribed components in the org (actives one).
The thing is that when I repeteadly press the refresh button. That notify new connection, gets sent and other components receive it. However sometimes the disconnection notification (the one that should be sent from the beforeunload callback) does not get sent. Which is causing the other components to still reflect a connected instance that has been replaced with a new one after the refresh button is pressed.
This is the initial code flow:
connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Im new');
        this.initializeComponent();
    }

initializeComponent = () => {
        this.initializerInterval = setInterval(this.intervalInit, 500);
    }

intervalInit = () => {
        if (!this.firstTimeRendered) {
            if (this.recordId) {
                this.recordHRef = window.location.href;
                this.firstTimeRendered = true;
                this.destroyInitializerInterval();
                this.onLoadInterval = setInterval(this.initOnLoadInterval, 200);
            }
        }
    }

initOnLoadInterval = () => {
        console.log(document.readyState);
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeUnload);
            this.destroyOnLoadInterval();
            this.initComponents();
        }
    }

initComponents = async () => {
        console.log('calling init Components');
        const userInfo = await getCurrentUser();
        const { id, status, name } = userInfo;

        this.status = status;
        this.instanceId = id + '-' + this.recordId;
        this.userName = name;
        this.userId = id;
        this.addWindowListeners();
        this.subscribeToEvent();
        this.initIdleCounter();
    }
    
subscribeToEvent() {
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (event) => { this.handleEvent(event) })
            .then(response => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.subscription = response;
                console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.subscription)));
                this.notifyConnection(); // Here It notifies the connection
            }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }

notifyConnection() {
        console.log('I subscribed');
        this.publishPlatformEvent('notifyConnection', 'Connection', 'All');
    }

initIdleCounter = () => {
        this.idleInterval = setInterval(this.intervalActions, 1000);
    }

intervalActions = () => {
        if (this.idleTimer > 0) {
            this.idleTimer -= 1;
        } else {
            if (this.status == 'Active' && !this.disconnecting) {
                this.status = 'Idle';
                this.publishPlatformEvent('intervalActions', 'Status', 'All');
            }
        }
        if (!this.afk && window.location.href != this.recordHRef && !this.disconnecting) {
            this.afk = true;
            this.status = 'Idle';
            this.publishPlatformEvent('intervalActionsAFK', 'Disconnection', 'All');
            this.membersMap = {};
        }
        if (this.afk && window.location.href == this.recordHRef) {
            this.afk = false;
            this.status = 'Active';
            this.publishPlatformEvent('intervalActionsReconn', 'Reconnection', 'All');
        }

        if (window.location.href == this.recordHRef && !this.onURL) {
            this.onURL = true;
        }
    }

publishPlatformEvent(methodName, eventType, target, disconnected, uniqueTargetId) {
        if (document.readyState != 'complete' && methodName == 'notifyConnection') { // I 
            //even tried with this, and it is not making any difference
            console.log('Did not get to load');
            this.removeSubscription();
        } else {
            console.log('published from ', methodName)
            const name = this.userName;
            const status = this.status;
            const source = this.instanceId;
            const uniqueSourceId = this.subscription.id;
            publishUserEvent({ source, name, status, eventType, target, recipient: null, uniqueSourceId, uniqueTargetId, methodName })
                .then((response) => {
                })
                .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            if (disconnected) {
                this.removeSubscription();
            }
        }
    }

Please I would be more than glad if you can help me understand a what am I doing wrong on trying to bulletproof this specific issue

Browser makers note that the event is unreliable as an aside in announcing the deprecation of the unload event. If you are not using the event to block navigation, consider using one of the replacement events for unload they list.

Is there a reason you need to detect the disconnect instead of simply announcing the connect, as the component is first rendered?
